# Unable to set camcorder profile for android video recording application

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture, video-recording, android-mediarecorder

Following code is not allowing to record a video. This code is invoked through a button but the button freezes. I am trying to use the camcorder profile to record the video.

```
    public void startRecording() {

    mCamera.unlock();
    mrec.setCamera(mCamera);
    CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    mrec.setProfile(cpHigh);        

    File dir = new File(SdCardPath + Directory);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        if (dir.mkdir()) {
            Log.v(STORAGE_SERVICE, "Created directory");
        } else {
            Log.v(STORAGE_SERVICE, "Failed to create Directory");
        }
    }

    FullFilePath = SdCardPath + Directory + RecordFileName;

    mrec.setOutputFile(FullFilePath);
    mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
    try {
        mrec.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mrec.start();
}
```

Comment: I just looked at logcat an found that it's an attempt to use a locked camera from a different process -> 
`java.lang.RuntimeException : unlock failed `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always do you best to catch exceptions thrown:

```
public void startRecording() {

    try {
        mCamera.unlock();
    catch (RuntimeException ex){
        //  looks like camera was locked in the first place, who is using it? 
    }
    mrec.setCamera(mCamera);

            ///...the rest of your code.
}
```